# Is "affectated" a real word, an adjective for something demonstrating affectation?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I have used the word "affectated" in conversation many times in the past, but when I went to write it, my spell-checker balked. "Affectated", meaning someone or something that is demonstrating affectation, which is "behavior, speech, or writing that is artificial and designed to impress".

"Affectated" is not in most of the online dictionaries I've checked. It is listed at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affectated, but nowhere else.

Is it a real word?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't coined a new word but have picked up an old and disused one. The *OED* reports that *affectate* is the "more Latinized" form of the verb *to affect*. The past participle *affectated* once had the same meaning as its simpler, less Latinized cousin *affected*, i.e., studied display. Thus from 1580

> A stile [sic] of oration to [sic] much **affectated** with strange words

As the word hasn't been seen in print in about 400 years, using it would be, well, affected. Your spell-checker is right to flag it.

Comment: Ah! I misread the Wiktionary listing. That's a bit of a bummer. I got some up-votes too :-]

Comment: Let's not exaggerate.  The OED has a quotation from as recently as 1761.  "1761   tr. C. Batteux Course Belles Lettres IV. iii. iii. i. 252   There should be no places of words, nor change of letters, for the sake of introducing a grace, or the affectated arrangement of every member of a period".   A mere 256 years ago. But +1 anyway.

Comment: @ab2 Sorry. I blame my eyesight for the oversight. And the drugs, of course.